# How can i make Http request again in retrofit to get updated data from api

Tags: mvvm, gson, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose, okhttp

I want to update the data I'm getting from api to display it in my lazy column, I'm trying to add swipe down to refresh functionality.

I'm getting the data from my viewmodel

```
@HiltViewModel
class MatchesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val matchRepository: MatchRepository
): ViewModel()  {

    val response: MutableState<ApiState> = mutableStateOf(ApiState.Empty)

    init {
        getAllMatches()
    }

    private fun getAllMatches() = viewModelScope.launch {

        cricketRepository.getAllMatches().onStart {

            response.value = ApiState.Loading
        } .catch {

            response.value = ApiState.Failure(it)
        }.collect {

            response.value  = ApiState.Success(it) }
}
}
```

then i made new kotlin file where I'm checking if I'm getting the data and passing it in my lazy column

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(viewModel: MatchesViewModel = hiltViewModel()){

    when (val result = viewModel.response.value){

        is ApiState.Success -> {
            HomeScreen(matches = result.data.data)
        }

        is ApiState.Loading -> {

        }

        is ApiState.Empty -> {

        }

        is ApiState.Failure -> {

        }
    }
}
```

i want to know how can i make the request again to get the updated data

after some googling i found out you can retry api calls with okhttp interceptors but could'nt find any documentation or tutorial to retry calls with interceptor

Comment: Add public method `refresh()` that calls your private method `getAllMatches()`. Call `viewModel.refresh()` on onRefresh method of `SwipeRefresh` composable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Swipe to Refresh with the accompanist dependencie

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:0.26.5-rc"
```

Implementation would be like this

```
val swipeRefreshState = rememberSwipeRefreshState(false)
SwipeRefresh(
        state = swipeRefreshState,
        onRefresh = {
            swipeRefreshState.isRefreshing = false
            viewModel.<FUNCTION TO LOAD YOUR DATA>
        },
        indicator = { swipeRefreshState, trigger ->
            SwipeRefreshIndicator(
                // Pass the SwipeRefreshState + trigger through
                state = swipeRefreshState,
                refreshTriggerDistance = trigger,
                // Enable the scale animation
                scale = true,
                // Change the color and shape
                backgroundColor = <UPDATE CIRLE COLOR>,
                contentColor = <RELOADING ICON COLOR>,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(50),
            )
        }
    ) {
        <CONTENT OF YOUR SCREEN>
      }
```